# Is there a term for a game that is not technically zero-sum but where cooperation is always worse?

Tags: terminology, game-theory

I know a little about game theory, zero sum and positive sum games etc.  I'm wondering if there is a specific term for a situation where a game is not technically zero sum but which still has similar feel to a zero sum game where cooperation is strictly worse and one person's benefit is generally at the detriment of another.

So for an example imagine a game where both players have an option to either cooperate or compete.  If they cooperate each player earns X.  If the compete player A earns 2X while player B earns .1X.

This game is not technically zero sum, since in the compete option player A gains more then player B looses leading to a net gain.  However, it still feels similar to a zero sum game in that there is never a motivation for cooperation, the incentive is to compete, and one player's benefit always comes at another player's loss.

Is there a commonly agreed upon term for this sort of situation in game theory?

Comment: The Wikipedia page for "Zero-sum game" suggests you could call it a "competitive game", but I have no idea if that's standard.

Comment: @MarkS.Yeah I looked through wikipedia's article before posting here.  I agree competitive game was the best term I could find from the article, but it still seemed a general term, ie all the games like the ones I described would be competitive games, but not all competitive games would be ones that fit my definition.  Of course I"m not sure there *is* a term specifically for what I was thinking of so it may be the best you can get.

Comment: Non-cooperative games can have outcomes where cooperation would be better but there is incentive for one player to deviate so the equilibrium is to not cooperate, and these can be non-zero-sum games.